# have a chip on one's shoulder

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've read the meaning of the phrase "have a chip on one's shoulder"- "to be aggressively sensitive about a particular thing or bear a grudge". Does it mean that this **person is weak** (not strong), he has some psychological problems and most probably he **isn't dangerous**?

I've found some examples and it seems they confirm my explanation, don't they?

> Don’t take him seriously, he just has a chip on his shoulder.
>
> “We'll get along as he just has a chip on his shoulder.

Comment: The short answer is: no, the phrase does not have any such meaning.  If you update your question to include your reasons for believing the phrase might have this meaning, we may be able to provide better answers.

Comment: I'm really curious why you think "have a chip on one's shoulder" means someone isn't dangerous.

Comment: @Juhasz, How could you explain my examples that include this phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dangerous individual might have a chip on his shoulder; someone utterly benign could as well. The phrase in and of itself isn't necessarily associated with any level of risk but it is a highly contextual phrase. Someone with a chip on their shoulder might seek to even the score. Someone else might just sulk in silence. It would really depend on the situation and person that it was applied to.